# Ext js combo box typehead crtl + v error

Tags: extjs

I have combo box and type head true. On change event I am making ajax request to get matched result.

If type there then its working fine, **But If I do copy paste in the Combo then it shows result but gives and error and blocks further flow**.

below is the code.

```
{
    xtype : 'combo',    
emptyText : 'Search',
       id : 'search',
    store : Store,  
    width : '50%',
 minChars : 3,
typeAhead : true,
   anchor : '100%',
listConfig : {
        emptyText : 'No Matching results found.',   
        getInnerTpl: function() {                   
            return '<div class="search">' +
                        '<span>{value} - {key}</span>'+
                    '</div>';
        }
    },
listeners : {
   beforequery: function (record) {
                // Added Condition to avoid weird JS error
                if(Ext.getCmp('search').getValue() != null && Ext.getCmp('search').getValue().length <= 4){
                    return false;
                }
        },
        select : function(combo, selection){
            var selectedVal = selection[0].data.value;
            Ext.getCmp('search').setValue( selectedVal );
        },
        change : function () {
            if( Ext.getCmp('search').getValue() != null && Ext.getCmp('search').getValue().length > 4 ){ 
                var searchEle = Ext.getCmp('search');
                var searchType = Ext.getCmp('searchBy').getValue();
                var searchText = '%';
                searchText += searchEle.getValue(); 
                Ext.Ajax.request({
                        loadMask : true,
                             url : URL, 
                          method : 'GET',
                          params : {
                                searchText : searchText,
                                searchType : searchType,
                            },
                           scope : this,
                         success : function( response, callOptions ) {
                                        var myTempData = Ext.decode( response.responseText );
                                            Store.setProxy({
                                                type : 'memory',
                                                data : myTempData,
                                              reader : {
                                                                type : 'json',
                                                                root : 'data',
                                                       totalProperty : 'total',
                                                     successProperty : 'success'
                                                      }
                                                });

                                                Store.load({
                                                       scope : this,
                                                    callback : function(records, operation, success) {  
                                                                }
                                                });
                        },
                        failure : function(response, options ) {
                            loadmask.hide();
                            Ext.Msg.alert( 'Error', genericErrorMsg );
                        }
                    });
            }
        }   
}
```

The error is as below

[image]

The help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

**Json response**

```
{"value":"Test , user @  IB Tech: Strategic Change","key":"45804183"},
```

Comment: Try using ext-all-debug.js and then break into their code that's failing and see if inspecting the variables on the line that breaks tells you anything more.

Comment: I did but couldn't find prob. I'll try more. One more thing If I select value from drop down then its shows blank in combo due to that I wrote code to set the selected value, do you have any idea what could be the reason ?

Comment: Just a thought, I don't see any displayField or valueField config on your combo which are normally required for proper display

Comment: Yes I added it, Can I concat dislayField with the valueField to show result ?

Comment: Aren't you already doing that with your getInnerTpl definition of your listConfig?

Comment: Yes but once I select it from list then same value I want to show as selected value.

Comment: Can you supply a sample of what your JSON response looks like after performing a search?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply
JSON response added in question. I am done with showing and selecting the value. But still I'm struggling with the error so needs to solve it only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved it.

There was some problem with store.

I bind it after ajax success and removed it from initial config and it got solved.

```
Store.load({
             scope : this,
            callback : function(records, operation, success) { }
           });
Ext.getCmp('search').bindStore(Store);
```